# Most unsafe foods in zero gravity

Tags: microgravity, food, safety

[Mostly this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/812/can-you-have-birthday-cake-in-space) (and some earlier knowledge about food & drink behaviour in space) made me think that which are those foods that would mean a serious threat for people in space?

My two ideas are: foods that make a lot of crumbs (like chips) since those are floating in air and it may enter to the lungs of people. And drink, with the same reason with drops.

Comment: I am guessing that you are ignoring dangers to equipment (e.g., blocking air filters, short circuiting electronics) but possibly including bacteriological hazards (breeding grounds for bacteria/fungi). Even something as simple as making the opening of an access panel more difficult could increase risk to humans on board.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I can't see, why should I ignore the other dangers you mention. I just simply forgot them =) these threats are also serious and might be discussed here.

Comment: Zoltan: the most dangerous thing is booze. You can't take risks DUI at 17100 miles per hour.

Comment: Okay, @DeerHunter, it was [the second funniest thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers) I've ever seen in a SE site. Thanks :'D

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for the sort of site we are going for here.  There's a lot of wiggle room in your definitions, so I can imagine lot's of people throwing in their 2 cents.  Perhaps a more specific question would help:  "What are the dangers of eating chips in space?"  If you edit this question, we can see about opening it back up to answers.

Comment: @JonEricson I wanted to ask this question this way because there might be some kinds of food that may mean threat and we wouldn't expect for it. (e.g. pickles - just a funny example) Making it for one exact food type would give my main purpose away. Anyway, I don't mind if you see that it should be closed, because it didn't seem to be a bad question, so I don't lose anything.

Comment: Just so you're all up to date in case you missed it, @Undo has created a new discussion in our meta: [Is the 'microgravity food safety' question on-topic?](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/256/49). ;)

Comment: Thank you @TildalWave, I rarely use meta on most sites. SO meta is the only exception

Comment: @JonEricson Opinion based? Ironic enough, but there are actual catalogues of potential hazards and tons of sets of rules, which deal with such issues in human space flight. Going through the basic recommendations and risk analysis on food by e.g. NASA would give a wonderful answer. Voting for re-opening this question!

Comment: @ernestopheles: True enough.  But that's not what the question is (currently) asking.  Would you mind trying your hand at an [edit]?

Comment: @JonEricson I do not see the point in editing it. The current version is a good place to start - as good as it can get without some background in this field. If you have never seen e.g. a NASA guideline document in your life, you just can not imagine its complexity or way of thinking. So altering the question does not help. A good answer has to start here and work its way up into the high ground. 'There are no stupid questions, just stupid answers.' Please take care of the latter and people's two cents instead ...